# Is there a way to use persistent storage as virtual RAM in C++?

Tags: c++, ram, virtual-memory, solid-state-drive

I am working with a C++ program, from a bioinformatics publication, that used 128 GB RAM. Obviously, with an 8 GB laptop, I cannot run that. Is there a way, where I can use my SSD to be simulated as RAM to C++ program?

Comment: Shouldn't this be taken care of by your OS?

Comment: Your OS will do that automatically, although it might have some settings related to the maximum amount it will simulate. What OS are you using? Also: it WILL be horribly slow. And it might quickly kill your SSD with this huge load that an SSD was not meant for.

Comment: Memory _is_ RAM, at least as it is commonly used. What you're talking about is _virtual memory_, which means using a file on disk, called a swap file, to supplement RAM, and that is handled for you by whatever operating system you're working on. However, I suspect that even with an SSD, the speed might not be that great and SDDs tend to be sensitive about how many times a specific region is written to, so you might want to consider that as well.

Comment: The apparent confusion with terminology notwithstanding, If you're running a decently clothed 64-bit OS and process, chances are it will already do it for you. In theory you have 16 exabytes of addressable space (16-billion gigabytes, give or take). What you need should be available so long as there is paging space on your storage media and the OS is configured to utilize it on-demand.

Comment: In case of windows configure your page file to be stored in your SSD, in case of Linux - create a swap partition on SSD.